# Input for percentage values

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

I have some inputs on my webapp where we're asking the user to enter percentage values (e.g 10.75%, 23%).  Currently, they have to enter these values as decimal (e.g. 0.1075 , 0.23).

This is causing confusion for some users, so I was hoping there was a way I could convert the values to and from these formats (the backend has decimal values, the HTML inputs display the percentage values).  Is there a solution to this without having to roll-my-own with javascript or the like?

I didn't see anything in the HTML5 inputs that would do this, and I wasn't able to find a javascript lib that would do it easily.

What way have other people been doing percentage inputs in HTML?

---

**Additional Info**

The webapp is using Java/Spring, so the values coming to the HTML page are coming string from the java objects in question, so ideally I'm looking for something that doesn't take any backend coding.

---

**Answer**

It turns out that Spring 3.0 will do this automatically.  Annotating the fields in question with:

```
@NumberFormat(style = NumberFormat.Style.PERCENT)
private BigDecimal rate;
```

Will do all the conversion to and from the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript required is very simple. For example you could store the fraction value of the user's input in a hidden field when the user submits.

```
​<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="myPercent" name="myPercent" />%
    <input type="hidden" id="myFraction" name="myFraction" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() {
        document.getElementById('myFraction').value = 
            document.getElementById('myPercent').value / 100;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple math... 75 to .75 is 75/100. Include a line which converts the numbers after they submitted them.

Comment: Ideally I was hoping to do everything in one input box (without using hidden fields).  It might be a bit confusing to the user if 10.75% changes to 0.1075 after losing field focus.

Comment: Can't you do it on submit then? Display a "%" character after the input box, they type 75, then when you submit the form you divide by 100?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Let them type in the 75. When they submit it, you divide it by 100 in your code...and if you want to return a percent value just multiply it by 100 and then return it. Maybe you need to give us some more information on how your webapp works.

Comment: I've added some extra info to the question.  The values are coming straight to/from java objects, so I was looking to avoid backend code changes if possible.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly You could use the css pseudoclass `:after` to add a percentage sign after the input box.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly I'm affraid that you have to accept the fact that in programming 75% is .75 . Thats just they way how it works :) Therefore you will have to calculate the percentage value if you want the user to type in 75. It's not a big deal though, just create a function to convert the input and call it whenever you need it.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more elegant way.  I'll have to multiply all the values by 10 when populating the input fields also.

Comment: Even though I found a spring specific answer that does what I need, I accepted this answer, since it looks like this is the HTML/Javascript way to do it!